# Unexpected identifier error - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new to SpriteKit and objective c so I am playing about and I have reached an error message which I have been unable to fix. I get an unexpected identifier message and I am unsure why. I am doing it this way as I want to understand the way functions work in objective-c. I was wondering if someone could help me in the right direction as to this issue.

The code is this.

```
@implementation HMGameScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        SKSpriteNode *lvl1_bg_image = [HMGameScene set_lvl1_bg];
        [self addChild:lvl1_bg_image];
    }
    return self;
}

+(SKSpriteNode*) set_lvl1_bg {
    SKSpriteNode *lvl1_bg_image = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"lvl1bg"];
    return [SKSpriteNode *lvl1_bg_image]; // The error is here
}
@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `return lvl1_bg_image;`.  The square bracket syntax is `[receiver message]` where the receiver is some object (or class) and the message resolves to some method you want invoked.  Since you're not trying to call any `SKSpriteNode` method and `*lvl1_bg_image` is a pointer, not a message, the compiler doesn't like the syntax.

Comment: wow thanks, that worked. I'm a java programmer so the world of Objective C is new to me. Thanks